# How to store files on android directory and access it on React Native not using AsyncStorage and other storage medium

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to store a file on React Native, that once the system store that particular file, you won't need to rely on localhost to provide the access to the file itself.

I have a react native directory with files as shown:

```
    ...
     |-android
     |-ios
     |-node_modules
    ...
     |-App.js 
     |-tensorflow_inception_graph.pb 
     |-labels.txt 
     |-result.js 
     | 
    ...
```

I'm importing the "tensorflow_inception_graph.pb" using the following line of code:

```
import model from 'MyTensorFlow/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb';
import model from 'MyTensorFlow/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb';
```

Likewise, I have also tried using the following line of code:

```
import model from './tensorflow_inception_graph.pb';
import model from './tensorflow_inception_graph.pb';
```

**Result that I hoping to get:**
I could run the application and access the files stated above without ever getting the error message like [Debugging on physical phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DGOP.png).  This indirectly also means that I could run the application without attach the cable to my physical phone.

I wonder am I doing wrongly in the first place, I find the documentation provided by the 'react-native-tensorflow' is inadequate for a beginner to react native like me.

I hope someone can shed some light on this for me.  Thank you.

Comment: Update: If one were to use the hard-coded way (not encourage), by hard code your file directory path in search for the **tensorflow_inception_graph**, you would find it work in most cases.
`file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.<your_project_name>/files/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb` 
however you do need to physically put that file onto the the specified path in order for the system to locate it.

Comment: Still I'm hoping someone could help solve the problem that I faced.

Comment: Hi. I'm also looking for something similar. did you find anything. however, check this out `react-native-fs`. this package might help you.